# why do i see my own timeline tweets and not user's?

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to view another user's tweets. The other user is following me and i am following the user on twitter. But when i try this, i only see my own tweets, no matter what name i enter as argument for GetUserTimeline. 
What should i do??

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='', consumer_secret='', access_token_key='',access_token_secret='')
statuses = api.GetUserTimeline('chooimooi')
for tweet in statuses:
    print tweet
```

Also, how can i export this data to a text file?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at pydoc for twitter.Api.GetUserTimeline

```
pydoc twitter.Api.GetUserTimeline
```

which states:

```
twitter.Api.GetUserTimeline = GetUserTimeline(self, user_id=None, screen_name=None,
since_id=None, max_id=None, count=None, include_rts=True, trim_user=None,
exclude_replies=None) unbound twitter.Api method
```

I think therefore that putting **screen_name='usernamerequired'** will work. For example

```
statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name='chooimooi')
```